# Type sensitive dict in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, inheritance, types

Python 3 knows the difference between `1` and `1.0`:

```
>>> type(1)
<class 'int'>
>>> type(1.0)
<class 'float'>
```

Still, if I try to use both as keys in an ordinary dictionary, the are treated as the same (I'm guessing that is because both `hash(1)` and `hash(1.0)` is `1`):

```
>>> {1: 'one', 1.0: 'one point zero'}
{1: 'one point zero'}
```

What I would like is to have a dictionary-like object `my_dict` such that

```
>>> my_dict
{1: 'one', 1.0: 'one point zero'}
>>> my_dict[1]
'one'
>>> my_dict[1.0]
'one point zero'
```

Is the some subclass of `dict` that is sensitive to the type of each key?

Otherwise, I guess I have to create my own derived class and override the `__init__`, `__getitem__`, `__setitem__` and `update` methods? If so, I'm thinking that instead of using `key` as a key, I should use `(type(key), key)` as a key when accessing the item in the `dict` superclass.

---

**Edit:** The reason I want such a dictionary is because I have defined the class `AutoEnum`:

```py
from enum import IntEnum, auto

class AutoEnum(IntEnum):
    def _generate_next_value_(self, _start, count, _last_values):
        return count
```

(I have based it on the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#using-automatic-values)). Using this class, you can define new enumerations for which the values of the members are automatically assigned, starting at 0, and increasing by 1 for each new member, like so:

```py
class Fruit(AutoEnum):
    apple = auto()  # 0
    pear = auto()  # 1
    banana = auto()  # 2
    orange = auto()  # 3

class Animal(AutoEnum):
    cat = auto()  # 0
    dog = auto()  # 1
```

I want these to be enumerated like this because I have NumPy arrays in which I use these as indices. I also want a dictionary-like object that can take these as keys and that differentiate between keys that are converted to the same int value but are members of different classes, because sometimes I treat keys from both classes in the same code.

If I try to do the following:

```py
description_dict = {
    Fruit.apple: 'A round fruit with a thin peel',
    Fruit.pear: 'An oval fruit with a thin peel',
    Fruit.banana: 'An oblong fruit with a thick peel',
    Fruit.orange: 'A round fruit with a thick peel',
    Animal.cat: 'A pet that can accept you under certain circumstances',
    Animal.dog: 'A pet that always loves you',
}
```

the ditionary doesn't turn out the way I intend it to:

```py
>>> for key, val in description_dict.items():
...   print("{}: {}".format(repr(key), repr(val)))
... 
<Fruit.apple: 0>: 'A pet that can accept you under certain circumstances'
<Fruit.pear: 1>: 'A pet that always loves you'
<Fruit.banana: 2>: 'An oblong fruit with a thick peel'
<Fruit.orange: 3>: 'A round fruit with a thick peel'
```

Comment: "*because both hash(1) and hash(1.0) is 1*"—More to the point, it is because `1.0==1`.

Comment: Sorry for the obvious question but, why would want this? As stated by @khelwood, `1.0==1` is there for a reason

Comment: @khelwood But when you try to insert a key–value pair in a dictionary, they key is always hashed first, right?

Comment: @HelloGoodbye Even if they have the same hash, they will not be considered the same key unless they are `==`.

Comment: @khelwood Ok, I believe you. The reason I asked is because it would be very slow to compare a key to every other key in the dict with the `==` operator when inserting a new item, since it would take O(n) time (n is the number if items already in the dict). But if the dict implementation also use the `<` and `>` operators I guess it becomes O(log(n)) time.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye It figures out which hash bucket using the `hash` of the key, but it figures out whether keys are equal using `==`. It only has to compare each key to any key that has the same hash.

Comment: @OferSadan I have several `Enum`-derived classes, each with members with values 0, 1, 2 and so on, and I want a dictionary where the these members will be used as keys and should distinguished both by which value they have and by which Enum class they are in. A normal dict only considers the value of the member, not which Enum class it comes from.

Comment: @khelwood Okay? Then I'm again starting to doubt what you wrote originally. I could implement a class in which I override the `__eq__` operator to always return `True`, but implement a `__hash__` method that returns unique hashes for different instances. In that case, it seems to me that for two objects `a` and `b`, it doesn't matter that `a == b` if they still end up in different hash buckets and therefore never are compared using the `==` operator.

Comment: @khelwood I guess you're right in the case of `1` and `1.0`; the have the same hash so they are compared by the `==` and this becomes decisive.

Comment: If you have two objects being equal but having different hashes, you are creating a dysfunctional hash that can cause bugs. If you want to create objects with different hashes, then you should also make them not equal. On the other hand, if you make them not equal, it doesn't really matter if they have the same hash: they will still work as separate dict keys.

Comment: @khelwood Hm, okay I guess you have a point.

Comment: While there *are* important use cases for being able to do something like this, just checking key types isn't enough for a lot of those use cases. `(1, 1.0)` and `(1.0, 1)` are equal tuples with equal types, but not the kind of thing you'd want to consider equivalent for these purposes.

Comment: @user2357112 That's true. Although in my case, looking only at the values (as discriminated by the `==` operator) and the types would be enough.

Comment: "A normal dict only considers the value of the member, not which Enum class it comes from" That is false. Different enum members from different enumeration types shouldnt be equal **unless** you've done something like `class MyEnum(int, enum.Enum)`, i.e. created an "int enum". But that **fundamentally breaks** what an enumeration is for, and shouldn't be done, unless you are trying to maintain compatibility with an older API that just used `int` objects. *This is your fundamental problem*. Please provide a [mcve] to confirm

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga What I have done is `class AutoEnum(IntEnum):` with the only method `def _generate_next_value_(self, _start, count, _last_values):` with the only internal line `return count` and nothing more inside the class. Why do you mean that this breaks what an enumeration is for? I have based my code on an example from the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#using-automatic-values).

Comment: @HelloGoodbye yes, **don't do that**. This is *explicitly noted* in the docs: "For the majority of new code, `Enum` and `Flag` are strongly recommended, since `IntEnum` and `IntFlag` break some semantic promises of an enumeration (by being comparable to integers, and thus by transitivity to other unrelated enumerations). `IntEnum` and `IntFlag` should be used only in cases where `Enum` and `Flag` will not do; for example, when integer constants are replaced with enumerations, or for interoperability with other systems." This is your fundamental problem right there

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have updated my question for my specific need. Maybe my case would classify as "when integer constants are replaced with enumerations"?

Comment: "I want these to be enumerated like this because I have NumPy arrays in which I use these as indices." that doesn't make much sense to me. This really doesn't sound like a use-case for enums *at all*.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246590/discussion-between-hellogoodbye-and-juanpa-arrivillaga).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, the idea you have doesn't work as is, but an easy and slightly hacky workaround is converting them to strings first, since "1" and "1.0" will be considered distinct keys. The original value can of course be retrieved by converting it back.

Comment: I guess that works, but it would be more elegant if could just write `my_dict[1]` instead of `my_dict[str(1)]`.

Comment: Well, this solution preserves the ability to programmatically fetch the value you want with only an added string conversion, so I'd imagine it should be more or less the same for any practical purpose. Sometimes programming doesn't allow us to have nice looking things (looking at you, regex).

Answer (score 0):

If you do:

```py
class TypedDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, data=()):
        if isinstance(data, (list, tuple)):
            for key, value in data:
                self[key] = value
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return dict.__getitem__(self, TypedDict.get_typed_key(key))

    def __setitem__(self, key, val):
        dict.__setitem__(self, TypedDict.get_typed_key(key), val)

    def __repr__(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def update(self, other):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def keys(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def items(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    @staticmethod
    def get_typed_key(key):
        return type(key), key
```

then you can do

```py
>>> my_dict = TypedDict([(1, 'one'), (1.0, 'one point zero')])
>>> my_dict[1]
'one'
>>> my_dict[1.0]
'one point zero'
>>> my_dict[2] = 'two'
>>> my_dict[2.0] = 'two point zero'
>>> my_dict[2]
'two'
>>> my_dict[2.0]
'two point zero'
```

However, this code can't convert class instances to strings for the moment, nor call the `keys`, `items` and `update` methods, because they need to be reimplemented to ignore the types that are stored in the keys.

Moreover, since the actual need is to be able to use enumerated variables from different enumeration classes in dictionaries without having the dictionaries confuse one variable from one class with another variable with the same value but from another class, as well as being able to use them as indices in NumPy arrays, there are simpler, more practical solutions. (According to the discussion with @juanpa.arrivillaga, one such solution is to use `Enum` instead of `IntEnum`—this enables the direct use of ordinary Python dicts—and to simply explicitly retrieve the variable value through the `value` attribute when using it as a NumPy array index.)

Comment: While this solves the problem as stated, I suspect this is an example of the [x-y problem](https://xyproblem.info/). See the comment in the question that I just posted. You shouldn't have to do this with enums *unless you specifically inherited from `int`*. In which case, the best solution is to *stop doing that* and use enumerations the way they are supposed to be used